# Keras adding extra dimension to target (Error when checking target)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have a Siamese Keras model defined with this code:

```python
image1 = Input(shape=(128,128,3))
image2 = Input(shape=(128,128,3))

mobilenet = keras.applications.mobilenet.MobileNet(
        input_shape=(128,128,3), 
        alpha=0.25, 
        depth_multiplier=1, 
        dropout=1e-3, 
        include_top=False, 
        weights='imagenet', 
        input_tensor=None, 
        pooling='avg')

out1 = mobilenet(image1)
out2 = mobilenet(image2)

diff = subtract([out1, out2])

distance = Lambda(lambda x: K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(x), axis=1)))(diff)

model = Model(inputs=[image1, image2], outputs=distance)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                  loss='hinge',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Summary of the model looks like this:

```
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)             (None, 128, 128, 3)   0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_2 (InputLayer)             (None, 128, 128, 3)   0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
mobilenet_0.25_128 (Model)       (None, 256)           218544      input_1[0][0]                    
                                                                   input_2[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
subtract_1 (Subtract)            (None, 256)           0           mobilenet_0.25_128[1][0]         
                                                                   mobilenet_0.25_128[2][0]         
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_1 (Lambda)                (None,)               0           subtract_1[0][0]                 
====================================================================================================
Total params: 218,544
Trainable params: 213,072
Non-trainable params: 5,472
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

I am trying to train the model. My training routine looks like this:

```
for i in range(1000):
    X1,X2,y = data_source.getTrainingBatch(10, sameProb=0.5)
    y = y[:,0] // grab ground truth for class 0
    print(y.shape) // (10,)
    loss=model.train_on_batch([X1,X2], y)
```

X1 and X2 have shapes `(10, 128, 128, 3)`.

y has a shape `(10,2)` and is a list of one-hot encoded vectors for 2 classes. I only take ground truth for the first class and try to feed it to the model.

`print(y.shape)` statement prints `(10,)`, so the array is 1D. But when I run the code I get the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-bf89243ee200> in <module>()
----> 1 n=net.SiamNet("drug-net")

~/development/drug_master/net_keras.py in __init__(self, model_name, training)
     16                         print(self.model.summary())
     17                         self.data_source = data.BoxComparisonData()
---> 18                         self.train()
     19                         self.save()
     20                 else:

~/development/drug_master/net_keras.py in train(self)
     75                         X1,X2,y = self.data_source.getTrainingBatch(10, sameProb=0.5)
     76                         print(y.shape)
---> 77                         loss=self.model.train_on_batch([X1,X2], y[:,0].flatten())  # starts training
     78                         print("Loss (%d):" % i, loss)
     79                         if(i%20 == 0):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in train_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight)
   1754             sample_weight=sample_weight,
   1755             class_weight=class_weight,
-> 1756             check_batch_axis=True)
   1757         if self.uses_learning_phase and not isinstance(K.learning_phase(), int):
   1758             ins = x + y + sample_weights + [1.]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_batch_axis, batch_size)
   1380                                     output_shapes,
   1381                                     check_batch_axis=False,
-> 1382                                     exception_prefix='target')
   1383         sample_weights = _standardize_sample_weights(sample_weight,
   1384                                                      self._feed_output_names)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    130                                  ' to have ' + str(len(shapes[i])) +
    131                                  ' dimensions, but got array with shape ' +
--> 132                                  str(array.shape))
    133             for j, (dim, ref_dim) in enumerate(zip(array.shape, shapes[i])):
    134                 if not j and not check_batch_axis:

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected lambda_1 to have 1 dimensions, but got array with shape (10, 1)
```

As I understand the model expects the target has one dimension, in this case (10,), but receives a 2D target with shape (10,1). It seems like Keras adds an extra dimension to my target. What am I missing?

Keras version is 2.0.8

I use tensorflow as a backend (1.3.0)

Comment: That's strange.... sounds like y is actually not `(10,)`. Anyway, you could use `keepdims=True` in your `K.sum` to make the expected output be `(10,1)`.

Comment: Thanks. When I added `keepdims=True` the code runs. But I am still wondering why Keras adds an extra dimension to the target variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is strange.

It seems `y` is actually `(10,1)`.

You can use `keepdims=True` in your `K.sum` to make keras expect a `(10,1)` array.

---

Not sure what is the cause for that. Maybe you have old `Y` vars (perhaps upper case?) that were not erased and you're using them by accident?

Comment: Yeah, I checked that already. Also tried asigning it to another variable and passing that variable as the target. Same results. Your solution works, however it changes how the hinge loss function works. I'm not sure how it is supposed to be used, but the [implementation](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/losses.py) computes the mean over the last dimension, and when the extra dimension is added, this becomes useless (mean over one element is the element itself). I can get around that using my own loss function, but it would still be nice to know it's intended use.